# How can I browse Git Logs without Tig?

Tags: git

I have a new server provider and they have no tig installed, I am pretty sure the guys have some good reasons for that. How do you browse git logs without tig?

Not really what I am looking for:

1. `$ git log --graph --color --oneline --all --decorate`   # how can I browse things with this?
2. `$ git log -p`   # more like diff-less -combo, not really browsing.
3. `$ gitk`  # I am on console, although I could sshfs things but I want to browse things like with tig

Comment: Is it a debian or does it have headers installed? If yes, download/compile should be easy.

Comment: @Tass: yes well, my presupposition in this question is that I am ignoring something in `$ git log` or otherwise dump to use it. Perhaps, other people have found more clever ways to browse logs, not just tig (I feel a bit reinventing-the-wheel but I am not sure).

Comment: You mentioned sshfs in connection to gtk. Why not sshfs + tig? Anyway, I'm not trying to sound snarky, but: tig was written to do things git log can't do, so does it seem a bit unreasonable to ask how to easily get tig-like functionality while rejecting both tig and alternative git log -p --graph --etc + less soultions?

Comment: @wjl: I have no idea for historical goals with tig but I am supposed to substitute it somehow with `$ git log`. I doubt whether this is even possible, well I use currently just sshfs+tig as you mentioned (and I haven't really found any way to substribute sshfs+tig+gitk+etc things with just `$ git log`).

Comment: As wjl said, tig does things that core Git does not. Your alternatives to tig will all also be other programs, which probably aren't installed. (And I don't even know of any others that work inside terminals.) You seem to be ruling out all options. Do note that tig is a separate package from Git, so if you're just *assuming* that the admins deliberately didn't install it (and yet installed Git), you're probably wrong. Have you tried asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said, I'd suggest one of these:

1. git clone (maybe with --mirror) then just use tig. Advantages: it's all local, tig will be fast. Disadvantages: you have to keep your mirror copy up-to-date.
2. sshfs, then just use tig. Advantages: you are using your local tig, configured exactly how you want it, directly on the remote repository. Disadvantages: it might run a bit slow depending on sshfs network performance & caching.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the git log will be passed through `less` which will allow you to go up and down to view earlier or later history. `less` has a lot of functionality such as searching for certain strings, etc: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less

You should be able to use `gitk --all` to see everything as well.

Comment: ...press enter in tig so you realize what I mean by `browsing`.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, my personal config alias.lp

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cgreen%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cred(%cr)%Creset%C(yellow)<%an>'
```